# Determine what formula is in a cell

Tags: excel, compare, formulas

I have a spreadsheet that includes a pivot table.  In a cell next to the pivot table, I need to enter 1 of 2 possible formulas* based on the pivot table criteria selected.  What I am looking for is a way to determine at a glance which formula is in that cell now (so I know whether I need to switch to the other formula).

Any ideas?

*Before you ask, the 2 formulas are very complex and use multiple embedded "IF" statements which was too difficult to troubleshoot as one formula.  Plus, the one big formula was using too many system resources once it was carried down the 200K+ rows.  Easier to break it into 2.

Comment: many times there are easier methods with formula then nested ifs,  Maybe if you posted some data and what your formula are attempting we may be able to help simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

To see the current formula in a cell you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.